# append row to empty dataframe returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have empty dataframe generated from:

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['100', '75', '50'])
```

What I want to do is to append **Series object** into the `empty_df` with specific index:

```
    empty_df.loc['75'] = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3})
    empty_df.loc['100'] = pd.Series({'a': 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 6})
```

But, `empty_df` returns empty dataframe whose index is still 100, 75, 50.

The final result must be:

```
    a     b     c
100 4     5     6
75  1     2     3
```

Why does the addition of the **Series object** to specific index return empty dataframe?

Related solutions also do not work.

Comment: You wrote `emtpy_df` in the second code block instead of `empty_df`.

Comment: Shouldn't you initiate the `empty_df` with `columns=['a','b','c']`? `.loc` assignments seems to align the corresponding index, in this case, `columns`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That was my mistake. I modified it.

Comment: @QuangHoang It works correctly, if I set the columns to the empty data frame. But, how to append rows to dataframe whose columns are not set before appending?

Comment: You need to look at `pd.concat` or `merge`, or `join`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column names in advance, you should set them when creating the DataFrame, in which case you do not even need to set the `index`, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
empty_df.loc['75'] = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3})
empty_df.loc['100'] = pd.Series({'a': 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 6})

print(empty_df)
     a  b  c
75   1  2  3
100  4  5  6
```

If you do not know the column names in advance, you may as well use `append`, as follows:

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame()
empty_df = empty_df.append(pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, name='75'))
empty_df = empty_df.append(pd.Series({'c': 3, 'd' : 4, 'e' : 5}, name='100'))

print(empty_df)
       a    b    c    d    e
75   1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
100  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Beware, if you append a Series with the same name as a previously appended Series, it is not going to replace the values at that index in the DataFrame but simply going to append this new series with that same index, as follows:

```
empty_df = empty_df.append(pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, name='75'))
print(empty_df)
       a    b    c    d    e
75   1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
100  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0  5.0
75   1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't work, because your empty_df doesn't have these columns a, b and c, so we need to add these first.

So, let's say you don't know the column names in advance, then you can do add those with [.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

If you do know the column names in advance, then just use Clement Moline's solution.

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['100', '75', '50'])
series1 = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3})
series2 = pd.Series({'a': 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 6})

empty_df = empty_df.reindex(columns=series1.keys())

empty_df.loc['75'] = series1
empty_df.loc['100'] = series2

empty_df.dropna()
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    a   b   c
100 4.0 5.0 6.0
75  1.0 2.0 3.0
```